# What is the best way to dynamically load connection strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've seen some other posts in this topic, but thought I would ask the question with a description on my problem.

I have a login page which uses SQL provider for the user login. Then the user should be redirected to the main application. This is a web based CRM application in which we have multiple clients.

My goal is to use a single web site, but multiple SQL databases. And the user that signs in should use a connection string that corresponds to the company he belongs.

Any good ideas?

Comment: you mean, if you have 25 clients, then you have 25 databases?

Comment: No, he has 25 groups (companies) and 1 db per group. It's in the question.

Comment: Yes, 25 groups(with many clients), then 25 databases and one web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work to create a simple map between the user's organization and the appropriate database connection?

It could be as simple as a `Dictionary<string, string>` initialized in global.asax. The key would be the company and the name of a connection string defined in web.config.

If you need to make this configurable, you can load the values for such a dictionary from a custom configuration section.

Comment: That could work. But the problem is still to use the connection string from this dictionary to make a connection. I use LINQ for everything and need to be able to refference a connectionstring

Comment: In both LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities the data contexts have overloaded constructors that allow you pass a connection string. You can use those. You can't make it pick up a connection string from .config based on arbitrary logic.

Comment: Okay. I will take a look at this aproach

Answer (score 1):

Use ConnectionStrings in Web.Config. Check this link for more information : [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx). You can create a Key as the Name of the organization and value as the connection string that corresponds to the organization.

Comment: This is what I do today. The problem is that all the users are going to use the same web site, but differnet databases depending on the company wich they belong.

Comment: I think there is no problem. So how you are authenticating users? may be from a centralized Database right? After authenticating, pick the connection string from the Web.Config.

Comment: You mean I should save all the ConnectionStrings in the Web.Config, and after the user authenticated against the SQL server, then i pick the coresponding connectionString?

Comment: Yes. I mean that only - After authentication you can get the organization of the User, and you can load the connection string like
connectionstrings[variable].ConnectionString.